# Need a Jquery function to change Div content If value > 1000

Tags: jquery

Sorry, my Jquery is WEAK!

But here's what i have....

```
     $(function () {
              if (document.calc.loan.value > 1000)
              {
                  ("#link").value = "<a href='dump'></a>";
              }
              else {
                  ("#link").value = "<a href='dump2'></a>";
              }
     });

<form name=calc method=POST>
<input type=text name=loan id="amount" />
<div id="link"></div>
</form>
```

So I want the content of #link to change if the Loan Input is over 1000 as they type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) like below to modify the content of the div.

```
 $(function () {
     if (document.calc.loan.value > 1000) 
     {
        $("#link").html("<a href='dump'></a>");
     }
     else {
        $("#link").html("<a href='dump2'></a>");
     }
 });
```

Also you were missing `$`. Changed `('#link')` -> `$('#link')`

I just noticed that you want as he types in the input field. In that case you need an `onkeyup` event handler to check the value typed in the input box.

```
$(function () {
      $('#amount').on('keyup', function () {
           var amount = parseFloat(this.value);

           if (!isNaN(amount) && amount > 1000) {
             $("#link").html("<a href='dump'></a>");
           } else {
             $("#link").html("<a href='dump2'></a>");
           }
      }); 
});
```

**Edit**: Changed from `onchange` to `onkeyup`.

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense because `loan` doesn't have a value on DOM ready.

Comment: @pimvdb That is just the markup and the value could be set by any server side technology.

Comment: But the OP says "...as they type".

Comment: @pimvdb Just noticed and updating the answer

Comment: This seems very messy compared to @deifwud's answer in my opinion

Comment: @LeonardChallis Please feel free to comment on why it is messy?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#amount').keyup(function() {
  var url = ($(this).val() > 1000) ? 'dump' : 'dump2';
  $('#link').attr('href', url);
});
```

This will be triggered when the value of `amount` changes.